# Firefox Addon Pagemod not executed for youtube

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I am building a small add-on that interacts with the youtube website.
For injecting a custom script inside the page I use the convenient [page-mod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod) like so :

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*",
  contentScript: "window.alert('injected');",
  contentScriptWhen : 'start',
  attachTo: ["existing", "top"],
  onAttach: function(worker) {
    console.log(worker.tab.url);
  }
});
```

When I navigate through pages, the 'injected' message shows up each time a new page is loaded. But when it comes to youtube I got no result.

My visited urls are in order :

- `https://www.google.com` -> `injected`
- `https://www.google.com/?q=youtube` -> `injected`
- `https://www.youtube.com` -> `injected`
- `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lnUeovQ68Tw` -> nothing
- `https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=dark+side+of+the+moon` -> nothing
- and now on I never get an `injected` message if I stay on Youtube...

I noticed that when changing from video to video the url change but the webpage doesn't seem to reload...

I was able to get the `injected` message on a youtube video when I manually reload  it (`cmd+r` or `f5`).

As I searched I found [this article on page-mod's attachTo](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2012/09/12/introducing-page-mods-attachto/) which could have been a solution, but event with the `attachTo: ["existing", "top"]` line, the result was the same...

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While looking in another firefox extension lib I found a solution to my question :

> background.js

```
pageMod.PageMod({
  include : youtubeRegex,
  contentScriptFile : 'permanent.js',
  onAttach : function(worker){
    worker.port.on('update', function(){
      console.log('update from contentscript');
      worker.port.emit('include'); // call the script update
    });
  },
  contentScriptWhen : 'start',
});
```

> permanent.js

```
// 1st line of the file
self.port.emit("update");

// stuff called once
// ...

// stuff called on each udpate
self.port.on('include', function(){
  window.alert('injected');
});
```

This way I get a `injected` even in the youtube website.

Hope it will help :)

Answer (score 1):

YouTube changes the content of their site using JS. I am not sure if there are any events fired when youtube changes the location. The only event I know of is popstate, which fires, whenever the user navigates using the back or forward buttons (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate).

Comment: interesting, but meantime I was able to find a way to do it, if you're interested, see my answers to the question, thanks anyway :)